# bash / sed rewriting of variables for sip links

Tags: bash, sed, sip

im trying to use a bash script to replace all none numeric characters from a phone number,

here is a working exemple in php:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
        $nr = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', implode(" ", array_slice($argv, 1)));
        exec("qutecom -c call/0{$nr}");
?>
```

but i don't want to install php on all computers, bash with sed should be able to solve this, im just not good at writing sed commands, tried this whitout any luck

```
echo " sdf sdf sdf0736-41 43 51 sdfasfd " | sed -e "s/[^0-9]+//g"
```

that i hoped should return "0736414351"

---

my current solution

```
qutecom -c call/0`echo "$*" | sed 's/[^0-9]//g'`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply do:

```
echo " sdf sdf sdf0736-41 43 51 sdfasfd " | sed 's/[^0-9]//g'
```

Comment: so "+" isn't allowed in sed, tried without +, but i think that was before i had the g at the end, thanks